# Power Query - Table name variable

Tags: sql, powerquery

I am trying to use Power Query to retrieve a value from SQL Server. I want to parameterize the table name. Like I want to use cell value from one sheet (`Sheet1!A1 = Tablename1`).

How do I achieve above condition in Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

You may create named range **table** and refer to it:

```
= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Or use parameter table:

https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

Comment: Thanks Aleksei. But I would like to know how to get this parameter inside my SQL. Like Select * from Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]. I am trying to connect to MS SQL server, but each time table name will be different, for which I have to use some cell in the sheet.